# How can I add users to the agsadmin and agsusers groups (ArcServer)?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I have a problem with adding users to the agsadmin and agsusers groups in ArcServer.
How can I do the step?

I've tried but I can't find it: 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Configuring_a_one_machine_deployment/0093000000m6000000/

Comment: have you restarted the server? there are post-install requirements.

Comment: Which Server (Operating System) are you running?

Comment: oh....restart server? how...
Arcgis 10 server 
and i use win7-64

Comment: If you are running a 64-bit version of Windows 7, make sure you configure IIS and .NET to run in 32-bit mode (you can reboot your machine to restart)

Answer (score 3):

**Add users to the agsusers group on Windows**
On the SOM machine, start the Computer Management application. Computer Management can be found in the Control Panel under Administrative Tools.

Expand System Tools, then Local Users and Groups, then Groups.
Right-click the ArcGIS Server users group, named agsusers, and click Properties.

On the Property page, click Add and, in the dialog box that appears, add those operating system accounts to which you want to grant access to the GIS server. These are typically the accounts that people use to log in to the network from their own computer. Note: You don't need to add administrative users to this group. Administrative users already have user-level privileges to the services.

[image]

Window 7 (64 bit)  Control Panel >All Control Panel Items >Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Local Users and Groups - Administrators

Comment: I can't find "Local users and groups"
like the pic as below.....WHY@@
http://ppt.cc/oXQQ

Comment: If you are logged in as a user who is not a member of the administrators group, I don't think you'll be able to see "Local users and groups".

Comment: as Kirk mentions you do need to be an administrator to access this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to add users to the two groups?  If so, you'll want to go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Local Users and Groups -> Groups.  Double click the group you're trying to add users to, click Add, and enter the user you want to add (or search for a user through Advanced).